# How can I get the monday of a week in a special date in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

e.g. 01.10.2010 is friday => 27.09.2010 is monday.

I have no idea how to manage this one. btw: how can I calculate with dates?

Answer (score 6):

For [time/date calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) use NSDateComponents.

Listing 2  Getting the Sunday in the current week

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

// Get the weekday component of the current date
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

/*
Create a date components to represent the number of days to subtract from the current date.
The weekday value for Sunday in the Gregorian calendar is 1, so subtract 1 from the number of days to subtract from the date in question.  (If today's Sunday, subtract 0 days.)
*/
NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToSubtract setDay: 0 - ([weekdayComponents weekday] - 1)];

NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract toDate:today options:0];

/*
Optional step:
beginningOfWeek now has the same hour, minute, and second as the original date (today).
To normalize to midnight, extract the year, month, and day components and create a new date from those components.
*/
NSDateComponents *components =
    [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
               fromDate: beginningOfWeek];
beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

---

In later versions, there is a smarter way:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setFirstWeekday:2];    //2 is monday. 1:Sunday .. 7:Saturday don't set it, if user's locale should determine the start of a week
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *monday;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit  // we want to have the start of the week
       startDate:&monday             // we will write the date object to monday
        interval:NULL                // we don't care for the seconds a week has
         forDate:now];               // we want the monday of today's week
```

If you actually change the weekday that represents the start of the week (Sunday vs. Monday), you should change it back after this snippet.

Comment: looks very complicated :> . but it is a really good example. thank you